# Адаптация простого скрипта к разным элементам на странице

Tags: html, javascript

Доброго всем времени суток, господа

Есть скрипт `JS`. Назначение простое - скрывать/показывать определенный код кнопкой

```
// JS
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_hide() { 
    var div = document.getElementById('test1');
    if(div.style.display == 'block') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>

// HTML
<input type="button" onclick="show_hide();">
<div id="test1" style="display:none">
скрытый текст
</div>
```

В случае, если на странице появляется второй input `id="test"` - то первый естественно перестает работать. Если изменить `id` - скрипт уже не работает с данным `input`. Второй скрипт с аналогичным кодом и разницей в одну цифру делать не очень хорошо, хотя все будет работать.

Как переписать скрипт, чтобы он работал с разными `input`, у которых разные `id` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

перадавайте параметр id в тело функции и вызывайте ee    `show_hide("test1")`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function show_hide(id) { 
    var div = document.getElementById(id);
    if(div.style.display == 'block') {
        div.style.display = 'none';
    }
    else {
        div.style.display = 'block';
    }
}
</script>
```

Comment: сработало только с одинарными кавычками. спасибо.

    show_hide('test1')