# Поочередное добавление скрытых блоков кода на форму

Tags: javascript

Доброго всем времени суток.

Есть таблица, внутри которой форма. В таблице строки с 5й по 14ю одинаковые. Причем в форме заполняют обычно только инпуты только из первой строки (5й строки в таблице). Можно ли каким-либо образом скрыть строки с 6й по 14ю, и нажатием на какую-либо кнопку по одной добавлять скрытые строчки к таблице?

p.s. есть [решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/122819/%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D1%81%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B0-%D0%BA-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%BC-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%BC-%D0%BD%D0%B0-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B5), которое полностью устраивает в плане того, что работает. Самым главным плюсом является то, что код, выводящий форму,не нужно менять, но минус - придется засовывать 10 таблиц друг в друга, что не очень удобно.

Comment: решение приемлемо, только вот в таблице то нужно как то пометить строки, которые нужно скрыть?

Comment: достаточно того, что `tr` идут в таблице по порядку, [пруф.](http://jsfiddle.net/DbYZE/)

Comment: я весь в нетерпении влепить акцепт!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jQuery:

```
$('tr:gt(4)').hide(); // скрываем после пятой
$('tr:gt(13)').show(); // показываем после 14
```

т.о. образом можно скрыть необходимые вам строки, на счёт второй части вопроса не очень понятно

можно так:

```
var counter = 5;
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
    $('tr:eq('+ (counter++) +')').show();
})
```

[пруф.](http://jsfiddle.net/DbYZE/)

- [:eq()](http://api.jquery.com/eq-selector/)
- [:gt()](http://api.jquery.com/gt-selector/)